# IllegalArgumentException (java) from a class which extends RealmObject

Tags: java, android, realm

I am getting this error:

> IllegalArgumentException

while performing the below method. I have no idea why it is happening.

Any idea whats wrong here ??

```
    public void sendNoteWithoutImage(){

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // saving objects
    Note notesRealmClass = new Note();

    notesRealmClass.setTitle(titleStr);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ChannelIDs = TextUtils.join(" ",selectedItems);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    notesRealmClass.setObjId(objId);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // save object asynchronously
    Backendless.Persistence.save(notesRealmClass, new AsyncCallback<Note>() {
        public void handleResponse(Note note) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // new Contact instance has been saved
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully posted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Step 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("ERROR : ", "" + fault.getMessage());
            Log.d("ERROR Code: ",""+fault.getCode());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // an error has occurred, the error code can be retrieved with fault.getCode()
        }
    });}
```

As you can see i put numbered toasts to check which parts of the codes are executing. From step 1 to 4, everything is fine, but not in step 5. I am getting an error directly on step 6 and the error's print is:

> ```
> 02-18 12:54:09.025 25161-25161/pb.package D/ERROR :: rx/Observable
> 02-18 12:54:09.025 25161-25161/pb.package D/ERROR Code:: IllegalArgumentException
> ```

Comment: Please provide the line of code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: i think it is already there guys see `Backendless.Persistence.save(notesRealmClass, new AsyncCallback<Note>() ....` this line

Comment: @Rami what you mean by AsyncCallBack i didnt get it , maybe this is mine asynccallback class `Backendless.Persistence.save(notesRealmClass, new AsyncCallback<Note>()`

Comment: @remyboys Check if your database table fields match with *Note* object fields.

Comment: hey @Rami i checked it and everything was same

Answer (score 1):

Your issue should be when creating your Toast inside AsyncCallBack. Because you're using it inside an anonymous class, AsyncCallBack, you can't simply call getContext or getActivity because you are no longer in the scope of the Activity. Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(NameOfYourActivityClass.this, "Successfully posted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For example, let's say your Acitivity is called "NotesActivity" then you would do:

```
Toast.makeText(NotesActivity.this, "Successfully posted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: hey man thanks , apologise because i should mentioned before that my class extends realmobject and its a kind of bug which is throwing the error according to this  https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29233605-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-rx-observable-in-0-87-0  , i'll update  my question with full details and i got a work around for fixing  my problem ,  thanks again  for your effort